# The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type Future<Object?>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey there I am new to flutter and i am currently working on firebase with flutter I am getting the following error ,  The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Object?>?' ,The error occurs in the futurebuilder in future argument  ,

```
class messages extends StatelessWidget {
  const messages({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        final chatdoc = snapshot.data!.docs;
        final userdata = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: userdata,
            builder: (ctx, Snapshot) => ListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => messagebubble(
                      chatdoc[index]['Text'], chatdoc[index]['userId']),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                ));
      },
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chats')
          .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` returns a `User?` not a `Future`. Thus, you can access it without the `FutureBuilder`, just return the `messageBubble` widget :

```dart
return messageBubble(
 chatdoc[index]['Text'],
 userData?.uid)
```